# Segmentation Fault SIGSEGV while running C++ code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting error while executing my C++ code

**Error is:**
**The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.**

**Signal name: SIGSEGV**
**Signal meaning : Segmentation fault**

**IDE : QT Creator**

I know there is something wrong with the way I have declared the 2 dimentional array of structs in header file
But don't know exactly what!

Can someone please explain..

Please note, I plan to  create multiple instances of Datamatrix class as part of my work in a recursive or iterative manner.
Each instance containing 2 dimensional array of structs..
So Any help explanation is welcome.
There are many areas of C++ which I have not explored! still learning :)

Please see the code below

**main.cpp
----------**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "datamatrix.h"
#include "utils.h"

using namespace std;

void printArray(int items[],int size)
{
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
       cout<<items[j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello there" << endl;

    int a[250];
    for(int i=0;i<250;i++)
    {
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    printArray(a,250);

    DataMatrix *matrix = new DataMatrix();

    Utils u;
    u.myFunction(matrix); **<-- All goes well till here**
    cout<<"End of Main method"; **<-- This line of code is never reached**

    return 0;

}
```

**datamatrix.h
------------**

```
#ifndef DATAMATRIX_H
#define DATAMATRIX_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct KVPair { **<--- This is the line where issue comes**
    string key;
    double value;
};
class DataMatrix
{
public:
    DataMatrix();
    KVPair matrix[250][130];
};

#endif // DATAMATRIX_H
```

**datamatrix.cpp
--------------**

```
#include "datamatrix.h"

DataMatrix::DataMatrix()
{
    for(int i=0;i<250;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<130;j++)
        {
            string k = "f"+i+1;
            matrix[i][j].key = k;
            matrix[i][j].value = i+5;
        }

    }

}
```

**utils.h
--------**

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include "datamatrix.h"

class Utils
{
public:
    Utils();
    DataMatrix myFunction(DataMatrix* dm);
};

#endif // UTILS_H
```

**utils.cpp
---------**

```
#include "utils.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "datamatrix.h"

Utils::Utils()
{

}

DataMatrix Utils::myFunction(DataMatrix* dm)
{
    printf("inside myFunction ");
}
```

**Just thought to add console output as well(please see console output below)**

*Hello there
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 5
7 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147
148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167
168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187
188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207
208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227
228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247
248 249 250
inside myFunction*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: i think at least one line is a pure old C code

Comment: Why do you insist on C-style arrays so you have to explicitly pass their size? Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector`?  In *my* book, any use of C-style arrays in modern C++ is a code smell.

Comment: I cannot use template classes or dynamic memory allocation, its a constraint in my organization

Comment: @Rohit Then I'll argue that your organisation is *doing it wrong*.

Comment: `new` does dynamic memory allocation, doesn't it?

Comment: misra C guidelines also discourage use of template classes, thats what people here are following.. as its going to be used in real time systems

Comment: Some of this code is valid Java, too; just sayin'.

Comment: @ Maxim : Yes it does, but use strictly restricted to rare cases only

Comment: @RohitGaneshan `std::string` also allocates heap memory, doesn't it?

Comment: btw does anyone see any wrong with the way I created the 2-d array of struct in the header datamatrix.h ?

Comment: @RohitGaneshan That `DataMatrix` is over 1 megabyte of memory in size.  Returning it by value could easily exhaust the stack memory, since the stack memory is limited.  Second, your `myFunction` is supposed to return a `DataMatrix`, but you don't return anything.  Undefined behavior (and even if you did return something, that stack memory is still an issue).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Noted your comments regarding the stack memory issue.. as far as returning the Datamatrix, thats going to be there.. it's simply that i didn't put hell lot of lengthy code here and simply provided the one throwing the error

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
string k = "f"+i+1;
```

Causes the issue. It takes the address far beyond the string literal `"f"`, which is an invalid address, and passes that to `std::string` constructor, which reads from that address to determine the length of the string and causes the crash.

---

One way to fix would be:

```
string k = "f" + std::to_string(i + 1);
```

Comment: No, thats not the issue

Comment: I just changed it to string k = "f"; still the same error

Comment: @RohitGaneshan You need to recompile.

Comment: I did recompile

Comment: @RohitGaneshan You are probably hitting another error now. The error I described reliably causes `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: error same, line where error appears same, i even changed ```string key;``` to ```char key;``` and again in the constrcutor ```char k = 'f';```

Comment: right now I cleaned the project and recompiled and sounds like your point was valid.. will update in 4-5 hours though.. thanks for now

Comment: Maybe I am hitting another issue currently, Will post update after some more code changes

Comment: I found a pattern changing ```string k = "f"+i + 1;``` to  ```string k = "f"+std::to_string(i + 1);```  does not help, but changing it to ```char``` altogether causes the issue to disappear

Comment: *but changing it to char altogether causes the issue to disappear* -- All you did was probably move the bug to another place in your code.  If you don't know why a certain line of code fixes a problem, then it is not a fix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you mean to say that using the economical char , which uses much less memory is anyday better than string?

Comment: @RohitGaneshan From your question, maybe I'm missing something -- I still do not know what the actual goal is.  The reason is that entire line that uses `string` was faulty, so faulty that it doesn't make any sense looking at it.  So what were you trying to accomplish with that line of code?  Don't use C++, just explain what the final string(s) are supposed to look like.

Comment: The final strings are supposed to be like "f1"  to "f999" maybe  from "f5" to "f<some_integer>" depending on multiple factors

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the one warning from `gcc -Wall` prevents the crash. One way to do that is to add a return value in `Utils::myFunction`, as follows.

```
DataMatrix Utils::myFunction(DataMatrix* dm)
{   
    printf("inside myFunction ");
    return *dm;
}
```

It appears that `main` allocates space for a `DataMatrix` on the stack with the expectation that the call to `Utils::myFunction` will populate that space. The following `gdb` session excerpt on a binary with the added `return` statement in `Utils::myFunction` reinforces that claim.

```
(gdb) break main.cpp:30
Breakpoint 1 at 0xfaa: file main.cpp, line 30.
(gdb) run > /dev/null
Starting program: main > /dev/null

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:30
30      u.myFunction(matrix);
(gdb) print matrix
$1 = (DataMatrix *) 0x7ffff7e95010
(gdb) set $matrix = (DataMatrix *) ($rbp - 0x13d640)
(gdb) print matrix.matrix[249][129].key
$2 = "\030J\017\vw\b\200"
(gdb) print $matrix.matrix[249][129].key
$3 = <incomplete sequence \303>
(gdb) next
31      cout<<"End of Main method";
(gdb) print $matrix.matrix[249][129].key
$4 = "\030J\017\vw\b\200"
(gdb)
```

In my testing, the crash occurs during an attempt to deallocate an uninitialized `KVPair` consisting of arbitrary stack contents. The details of that are not revealed in the preceding `gdb` session excerpt, but the point is that after `Utils::myFunction` returns a value other than `void`, the two copies of the `DataMatrix` agree about the contents of the last array element (the first one processed in the destructor, in my testing). The following excerpt from `gdb` disassembly explains the `$rbp` offset used for `$matrix`.

```
   0x0000555555554fc7 <+183>:       lea    -0x13d640(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000555555554fce <+190>:       mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000555555554fd1 <+193>:       callq  0x555555555092 <DataMatrix::~DataMatrix()>
```

Another way to prevent the crash is to declare `Utils::myFunction` as returning `void`, in which case `main` does not allocate space on the stack, and there is no call to the `DataMatrix` destructor within `main`.